# Property 'RocketChat' does not exist on type 'Window'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, livechat

I'm using Reactjs and typescript for my app, and I'm trying to add RocketChat Livechat using some script which is provided by RocketChat. I added my script to typescript file for some conditional base display to the users, but it's showing some error (TS2339: Property 'RocketChat' does not exist on type 'Window'.)  which I unable to solve.

I tried to add RocketChat Property in Window object but not working.

Here is the code which is provided by RocketChat:

```
(function(w, d, s, u) {
    w.RocketChat = function(c) { w.RocketChat._.push(c) }; w.RocketChat._ = []; w.RocketChat.url = u;
    var h = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0], j = d.createElement(s);
    j.async = true; j.src = '/assets/rocketchat-livechat.min.js?_=xxxxxxxxx';
    h.parentNode.insertBefore(j, h);
})(window, document, 'script', '/chat/livechat');
```

Comment: where did you put that code ?

Comment: I put it in my index.tsx(src/index.tsx)  file, which app index file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added custom typings\custom-typings.d.ts file and I added below code, and it's working.

```
interface Window {
 RocketChat: any
}
```